# How can I see the traffic from a specified client to specified server [you name it!] communication in fiddler?

Tags: http, debugging, fiddler

I am wondering how I can see a sequence of requests in fiddler between my browser - the client - and a specific server?

Comment: Start Fiddler, look at requests?

Answer (score 0):

Using fiddler's filter we can accomplish this. Follow below steps.

a.  Make sure your traffic is going via Fiddler (both HTTP and HTTPs).

b.  Goto Fiddler’s filter tab.

c.  Click on **“Use Filters”** check box.

d.  Click on **“Show only traffic from”** and select the source from the dropdown.

e.  Click on **“Show only if URL contains”** and enter server [you name it!].

-Venkat

[image: Fiddler_Filter]